# Phusion Passenger could not spawn process for application - ruby on rails 4.2.8 ruby 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger, phusion

i am trying to run an application with phusion on ubuntu 20.04 and i got the following error:

```
[ E 2020-09-23 13:11:17.9564 7801/Tj age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/cylix/comlinked_app: The application encountered the following error: No such file to load -- sassy-maps/version (LoadError)
  Error ID: 2d832417
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-zpHwA5.html

[ E 2020-09-23 13:11:17.9652 7801/T9 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:274 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 2d832417. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
```

Comment: This is the important piece of information: _"No such file to load -- `sassy-maps/version`"_ Did you just add or remove the `sassy-maps` gem? Did you change anything to the `Gemfile`? How do you use that `sassy-maps` gem?

Comment: that sassy-maps gem was never included in the Gemfile, that is the reason for the question.

Comment: check out gemfile.lock.  even if you did not include it, one of your gems may be using it.

Comment: How does the file to which Passenger wrote the error details (`Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-zpHwA5.html`)?